# What are the best settings to run Ubuntu on a VM?

Tags: vmware, storage

What are the best settings to run Ubuntu on a VM?
Like how much storage and ram should allocate towards it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the host machine has the above ubuntu's recommended specs, I'd go with the recommended.

These are the recommended here:

1. 2 GHz dual core processor
2. 4 GiB RAM (allocated memory)
3. 25 GB of allocated storage

*[source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)*